# How to call element in another theme from view in current theme?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using CakePHP 2.4.2

Is there a way to call element from another theme in current theme?

e.g. inside `View/Themed/V1/Elements/a.ctp` is the element i want

but i want to call it from inside `View/Themed/V2/Pages/page.ctp`

I tried `$this->element('/theme/V1/Elements/a')` didn't work

What can I do to make this work other than copying the same element into the theme V2?

Comment: Put it in the overall View/Elements folder?  I don't think that it's all that good a design to depend on other themes, themes should be overrides for the default view imo.

Comment: echo $this->element('View/Themed/V1/Elements/a') from View/Themed/V2/Pages/page.ctp

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, element handels only the plugin prefix.
See the source code: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-View.html#363-415

In the line #1078 this function generates te file name what will be loaded

function _getElementFileName()

In the line #1100:

function _paths($plugin = null, $cached = true) ...

If you can change $this->theme value on the fly it should be work, but it seems like a hack sollution :)